# Bootstrap 4 change col position on differents sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm trying to display 3 cols in a different order and position, on display bigger or smaller then the "md" breakpoint.

On > md layout, the col "A" "B" should be one above the other, while the col "C" should be on the right of both of them.

On < md layout the col "A" should be 100% large, while the "B" and "C" should be on the same row.

I tried so far most of combination of bootsrap classes (for row and col), but haven't figured out how to reach this behaviour.

Attacched an image to better explain the question.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can - the first one would either need a and b in their own div (meaning you wouldn't be able to do the second one with the same html) or you would need to know the height of the div (meaning it would probably not be able to be responsive)

Comment: @Pete that's what i'am afraid of... I'd rather avoid duplicating one of the two divs, but by now seems the only way

Comment: You could try use a bit of js to move it, but that seems a little dirty.  What about using css grid - I reckon you could do something with that and some media queries, but I've not learnt it yet so wouldn't know

Comment: What about the heights, is this a full screen design? or you are expecting the height to increase in relation to the content the elements have?

Comment: The divs doesn't have a fixed height, they change in relation of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Using **<kbd>`Bootstrap 4`</kbd>** do something like this...

```css
.border-div {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 4px solid;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.c-div-block {
    max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
    max-height: calc(100% - 25px);
}

.border-div.normal-span {
    line-height: 100px;
}

.border-div.expanded-span {
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid my-5">
        <div class="row no-gutters position-relative py-2">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-9 order-first order-md-first">
                <div class="border-div border-dark text-center normal-span">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-9 order-2 order-md-last">
                <div class="border-div border-danger text-center normal-span">B</div>
            </div>
            <div class="position-absolute offset-md-9 col-md-3 order-md-2 h-100 d-none d-md-block">
                <div class="border-div border-success h-100 c-div-block text-center expanded-span">C</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 order-last d-block d-md-none">
                <div class="border-div border-success text-center normal-span">C</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Note: `div` width and height may differ as per your requirement, so do the adjustment on you own.**

Hope it will help many one.

Comment: I was thinking on something like this too, but he will have to define the inner html markup of `C column` twice (without using javascript or jquery).

Comment: Sure, it is possible using `JS` also, logic may differ individual vise, so I tried using `Bootstrap` and `CSS` only.

Comment: The solution i'm using now is quite similar, but without custom css or javascript code. I'm still not writing it since i don't find it a clean solution, but i had to duplicate the C div, below the A anb B and placed all of them in a row, that it's hidden on >= md layout (off course on < md layout the C div on the right will be hidden)

Comment: Oh, that's because the height of the different divs is not fixed!